# Angular subscribe returns undefined object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material, subscription

So i have material dialog, in this dialog i have button

```
<button mat-icon-button 
 (click)="getChoosenEmployee(element)">
</button>
```

Element is type Employee:

```
export interface Employee {
    index: number;
    employeeId: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

when i'm closing dialog i want to send this employee to parent component, this is what i'm doing:

```
  getChoosenEmployee(employee: Employee) {

    this.dialogRef.close(
      employee
    );
  }
```

in parent component i'm receiving by this function

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(this.choosenEmployee);
      this.choosenEmployees.push(this.choosenEmployee);
 });
```

pushing gives me error:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (add-workday-form.component.ts:72)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at Subject.next (Subject.js:39)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (dialog.js:381)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
```

Comment: Where is this.choosenEmployees instanciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you initialize your `this.choosenEmployees` array? That error is indicating that `this.choosenEmployees` is undefined, not the `this.choosenEmployee` object.

Comment: right i forget about it thanks, i feel stupid now :D

Comment: @NoobXDDD happens to the best of us :)